# Magento 2 error : Registry key "current_creditmemo" already exists

Tags: orders, creditmemo, refund

I am getting this error by programmatically creating credit memo.

any thoughts why this error is appearing ?

Comment: Hey, just by that I think it'll be hard, can you share the code you're using to create and save? Might be easier to someone to help with more info

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Comment: any thoughts on this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unregister "current_creditmemo" after initiating a new credit memo object.

try this

```
if (is_numeric($amount)) {
    $amount = max(0, min($creditmemo->getBaseCustomerBalanceReturnMax(), $amount));
    if ($amount) {
        $amount = $this->priceCurrency->roundPrice($amount);
        $creditmemo->setBsCustomerBalTotalRefunded($amount);
        $creditmemo->setCustomerBalTotalRefunded($amount);
        $creditmemo->setCustomerBalanceRefundFlag(true);
        if (!empty($tracking_info)) {
            $tracking_info_comment = implode("\n", $tracking_info);
            $creditmemo->addComment($tracking_info_comment);
        }
        $creditmemo = $this->creditmemoRepository->save($creditmemo);
        $this->registry->unregister('current_creditmemo');
        $this->creditmemoSender->send($creditmemo);
        $result[0] = true;
        return $result;
    }
}
if($this->registry->registry('current_creditmemo')){
    $this->registry->unregister('current_creditmemo');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below code to create a credit memo progrmatically

```
  $orderincrementid = "1000000001"
    $parentOrder = $this->orderInterface->loadByIncrementId($orderincrementid);
    $orderId = $parentOrder->getId();
    $orderItems = $parentOrder->getAllItems();
    $itemcol = [];
            
    foreach ($orderItems as $item) {
        $itemcol[$item->getItemId()] = [
             'qty' => $item['qty'],
             'back_to_stock' => 1,
            ];
    
    }
   $this->createCreditMemo($itemcol, $orderId, $parentOrder);
```

call your function

```
public function createCreditMemo($itemcol, $orderId, $parentOrder)
{
$creditMemoData = [];
$creditMemoData['items'] = $itemcol;
$creditMemoData['do_offline'] = 1;
$creditMemoData['shipping_amount'] = 0;
$creditMemoData['adjustment_positive'] = 0;
$creditMemoData['adjustment_negative'] = 0;
$creditMemoData['comment_text'] = 'comment_text_for_creditmemo';
$creditMemoData['send_email'] = 1;

try {

    $this->creditmemoLoader->setOrderId($orderId); //pass order id
    $this->creditmemoLoader->setCreditmemo($creditMemoData);

    $creditmemo = $this->creditmemoLoader->load();
    if ($creditmemo) {
        if (!$creditmemo->isValidGrandTotal()) {
            throw new LocalizedException(
                __('The credit memo\'s total must be positive.')
            );
        }

        if (!empty($creditMemoData['comment_text'])) {
            $creditmemo->addComment(
                $creditMemoData['comment_text'],
                isset($creditMemoData['comment_customer_notify']),
                isset($creditMemoData['is_visible_on_front'])
            );

            $creditmemo->setCustomerNote($creditMemoData['comment_text']);
            $creditmemo->setCustomerNoteNotify(isset($creditMemoData['comment_customer_notify']));

        }
            if (isset($data['do_offline'])) {
            //do not allow online refund for Refund to Store Credit
            if (!$data['do_offline'] && !empty($data['refund_customerbalance_return_enable'])) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                    __('Cannot create online refund for Refund to Store Credit.')
                );
            }
        }

        $creditmemoManagement = $this->_objectManager->create(
            'Magento\Sales\Api\CreditmemoManagementInterface'
        );
        $creditmemoManagement->refund($creditmemo, (bool)$creditMemoData['do_offline']);


        if (!empty($creditMemoData['send_email'])) {
            $this->creditmemoSender->send($creditmemo);
        }

    }
} catch (LocalizedException $e) {
    $this->_logger->info("Failed to create credit memo" . $e->getMessage());
}
}
```